# Suggested Tools for Visualizing a Subgraph DAG

Tags: graph, visualization, graphviz, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am writing a program which basically processes a subgraph DAG, i.e., the graph is a directed acyclic graph and each node of the graph is a subgraph. For example, for an edge `A->B` in the DAG, node `A` is a subgraph of a triangle and node `B` is a subgraph of a four clique. The edge `A->B` indicates an extension from a triangle to a four clique by adding one subgraph vertex and three subgraph edges.

```
 +=======+        +=======+
 | a---b |        | a---b |
 | |  /  |        | |\ /| |
 | | /   | =====> | | X | |
 | |/    |        | |/ \| |
 | c     |        | c---d |
 +=======+        +=======+
     A                B
```

For many purposes, I want to visualize this subgraph DAG, i.e., the visualization can show the entire structure of the DAG and show the subgraph of all the nodes at the same time. Also it would be better if it can also show properties of vertices and edges.

I am able to list all the nodes and edges of the DAG and the subgraphs of all the nodes in any format. But what I don't know is what tool is the best for such visualization. I tried [graphviz](https://graphviz.org/) by exporting the subgraph DAG into `dot` format and use graphviz to convert the `dot` file to a png. The problem of graphviz is it can show the subgraph of nodes very well but it fails to show the structure of the DAG in a human-readable way. It would be good if

1. for a DAG edge `A->B`, node `A` is placed above node `B`. (`graphviz` now puts all the DAG nodes in the same row)
2. the nodes are placed properly such that the intersection among the DAG edges is minimized.

Are there any other alternatives? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, I think this **dot** program comes pretty close:

```
digraph dag {
  compound=true  // needed for A->B edge (kludge, but documented)
  edge [dir=none]  // no arrowheads
  subgraph clusterA{
   labelloc=b
   label="A"
   Aa -> Ab // [constraint=false]  // keep on same rank
   Ab -> Ac
   Aa -> Ac
   {
   rank=same
   Aa [label="a"]
   Ab [label="b"]
   }
   Ac [label="c"]
}
  subgraph clusterB{
   labelloc=b
   label="B"
   Ba -> Bb // [constraint=false]  // keep on same rank
   Bc -> Bd // [constraint=false]  // keep on same rank
   Bb -> Bc
   Ba -> Bc
   Bb -> Bd
   Ba -> Bd
   {
   rank=same
   Ba [label="a"]
   Bb [label="b"]
   }
   {
   rank=same
   Bc [label="c"]
   Bd [label="d"]
   }
}
Ac -> Ba [dir=forward ltail=clusterA lhead=clusterB  minlen=2] 
}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was actually using similar approach to present the subgraph DAG in a dot format, i.e., using `cluster`, `compound=true`, `ltail` and `lhead`. The difference between mine and yours is the nodes used for DAG edges, i.e., you are using `Ac` and `Ba` in this example while I alway use the first vertex (i.e., `?a`) of subgraphs to connects the DAG nodes. That difference should be the problem.

Comment: Small note: with `dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)` (on windows) I get an image where the top block moved a bit to the left and is not completely above the bottom block (same happens when feeding the example in: http://www.webgraphviz.com/). When using `dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)` (on cygwin) the result is like the image in the answer.